# hanami 2.0 with sequel

Tags: ruby, hanami

I'm following this guide for getting started with `hanami`:

https://guides.hanamirb.org/v2.0/introduction/getting-started/

Rather than using ROM, I prefer Sequel, but I stumble upon the persistancy :

https://guides.hanamirb.org/v2.0/introduction/getting-started/#persisting-books

In my `gemfile`, I use `sequel` and `pg` instead of `rom`.

I added this to `config/app.rb`:

```rb
require "sequel"
```

and  `config/providers/persistence.rb` contains this:

```rb
Hanami.app.register_provider :persistence, namespace: true do
  prepare do

    #config = ROM::Configuration.new(:sql, target["settings"].database_url)
    config = DB = Sequel.connect(database_url) 

    register "config", config
    register "db", config.gateways[:default].connection
  end

  start do
    config = target["persistence.config"]

    # config.auto_registration(
    #   target.root.join("lib/bookshelf/persistence"),
    #   namespace: "Bookshelf::Persistence"
    # )

    register "sequel", DB
  end
end
```

`config/settings.rb`:

```rb
module Bookshelf
  class Settings < Hanami::Settings
    # Define your app settings here, for example:
    #
    # setting :my_flag, default: false, constructor: Types::Params::Bool

    setting :database_url, constructor: Types::String
  end
end
```

and finally, the database_url is defined in a `.env` and and `.env.test` file.

```
# .env
DATABASE_URL=postgres://thiebo@localhost:5432/bookshelf_development
```

Running this from the hanami console works fine:

```
moi@Hugo bookshelf % bundle exec hanami console
bookshelf[development]> Hanami.app["settings"].database_url
=> "postgres://moi@localhost:5432/bookshelf_development"
bookshelf[development]>
```

Sequel allows for migrations to be run as a rake task:
http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/migration_rdoc.html#label-Running+migrations+from+a+Rake+task

My Rakefile:

```rb
require "sequel"

namespace :db do
  desc "Run migrations"
  task :migrate, [:version] do |t, args|
    require "sequel/core"
    Sequel.extension :migration
    version = args[:version].to_i if args[:version]
    Sequel.connect(ENV.fetch("DATABASE_URL")) do |db|
      Sequel::Migrator.run(db, "db/migrations", target: version)
    end
  end
end
```

however... when I run try to run that migration from the console, as per Sequel documentation :

```
thiebo@Hugo bookshelf % rake db:migrate           
rake aborted!
KeyError: key not found: "DATABASE_URL"
/Users/thiebo/bookshelf/Rakefile:12:in `fetch'
/Users/thiebo/bookshelf/Rakefile:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/thiebo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/thiebo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
/Users/thiebo/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

(it also doesn't work with `database_url` instead of `DATABASE_URL`. Same error...)

Comment: It appears you are using `Dotenv` if so you should just be able to add `require 'dotenv/tasks'` and then namespace your rake task under the the :dotenv key or add `require 'dotenv/load'` which will load the .env files.

Comment: that was exactly it!

Comment: [rom-sql](https://rom-rb.org/learn/sql/3.3/) internally uses Sequel so I couldn't understand the explicit need for using Sequel. `rom-sql` provides a more user-friendly API and DSL for defining Sequel relations. Besides at https://github.com/jiggneshhgohel/startup_template you can find a working Hanami 2.0 CRUD application with a front-end. At the time of writing this Hanami 2.0 doesn't have out-of-the-box support for views and thus https://guides.hanamirb.org/v2.0/introduction/getting-started/ demonstrates building an API application. But in my referenced application has views integration.

Answer (score 0):

Hanami By default loads environment variables via Dotenv. You can just load it manually like @engineersmnky mentioned in the comment. Quoted his response for reference:

> It appears you are using Dotenv if so you should just be able to add require 'dotenv/tasks' and then namespace your rake task under the the :dotenv key or add require 'dotenv/load' which will load the .env files. –
> @engineersmnky

However, I prefer to just load the `hanami/prepare` in my rake tasks, which loads the same configuration as we have for console, keeping our tasks fast and clean, but automatically resolving all the config for you automatically.

I've an example of this in [configuring ROM from scratch tutorial](https://hanamimastery.com/episodes/28-configure-rom-from-scratch)

Long story short, by calling:

```rb
# rakefile
require "hanami/prepare"

* ....
```

In your rakefile, you'll load all the settings, resolved by preconfigured engine, which is `dotenv` in this case.

It's useful for example, when you would like to load environment/settings via different engine (from YAML for example?), and in that case, no change would be required in your rakefile.

Comment: How would you load the Sequel model? Using a provider?